# Passing multiple view parameters to a converter for an entity with a compound primary key

Tags: jsf, converters, omnifaces, multiple-value, viewparams

How do you write a converter for an entity with a compound primary key?

I want to edit the entity with a URl such as
`\edit_representative.xhtml?emp_id=12345&project_id=45

I'm using Omnifaces so I have something like this for single primary keys

```
<o:viewParam name="emp_id" value="#{projectRepEdit.projectRep}"
converter="#{projectRepConverter}"
converterMessage="Bad request. Unknown Project Representative." required="true"
requiredMessage="Bad request. Please use a link from within the system." />
```

but I how do pass the project_id the employee is working on to the converter

**EDIT**

Based on BalusC's answer I used the second option and have the following in my `projectRepConverter` Converter

```
String project_id = (String) component.getAttributes().get("project_id");
String emp_id= (String) component.getAttributes().get("emp_id");

ProjectRep prjRep = prjRepRepository.getByEmpIdAndProjectId(emp_id,project_id);
return prjRep;
```

and in the facelet

```
<f:metadata>
<o:viewParam name="project_id" value="#{projectRepEdit.project}"
    converter="#{projectConverter}"
    converterMessage="Bad request. Unknown Project." required="true"
    requiredMessage="Bad request. Please use a link from within the system." />

<o:viewParam name="badge" value="#{projectRepEdit.projectRep}"
    converter="#{projectRepConverter}"
    converterMessage="Bad request. Unknown Project Rep." required="true"
    requiredMessage="Bad request. Please use a link from within the system.">
    <f:attribute name="project_id" value="#{param.project_id}" />
    <f:attribute name="emp_id" value="#{param.emp_id}" />
</o:viewParam>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the `<f:viewParam>` nor the `<o:viewParam>` supports taking multiple parameters. You'd need to manually grab the parameter. I can think of two basic ways for this:

1. Either grab it as request parameter in the converter:

   ```
   String project_id = FacesLocal.getRequestParameter(context, "project_id");
   ```

   ---
2. Or pass it as component attribute:

   ```
   <o:viewParam ...>
       <f:attribute name="project_id" value="#{param.project_id}" />
   </o:viewParam>
   ```

   So that you can grab it as follows in the converter:

   ```
   String project_id = (String) component.getAttributes().get("project_id");
   ```

   ---

Which way to choose depends on the intented reusability of the converter. For instance, you can with the 2nd way rename the `project_id` attribute name to `compound_key` or so and make it reusable.

Comment: Option #2 achieved what I was after.